# Websocket code works in console but not in winform

Tags: c#, websocket

I try to do a websocket call with the library:

**using WebSocketSharp;**

The code works in the console like below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{                
    using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbbtc@ticker"))
    {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("Message received" + e.Data);

        ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);

        ws.Connect();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to work in a winform application. 
How would I set up the below code correctly? Nothing happens when I run the below code. I can't see any text in the richTextBox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(test).Start();
}

void test()
{
    using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbbtc@ticker"))
    {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
         Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.Text = "Message: " + e.Data; });

        ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
            Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.Text = "Error: " + e.Message; });

        ws.Connect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that if the call is not blocking on `ws.Connect()` your thread might be finishing and the socket object is being disposed.

In your console example you have `Console.ReadKey(true);` which blocks the main thread

You can try waiting on a ManualResetEvent

```
private ManualResetEvent manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

void test()
{
    using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbbtc@ticker"))
    {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
         Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.Text = "Message: " + e.Data; });

        ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
            Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate { richTextBox1.Text = "Error: " + e.Message; });

        ws.Connect();

        manualReset.WaitOne();
    }
}

void signalExit()
{
    manualReset.Set();
}
```